# Python: Area of a polygon

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong, I've been stuck on this for a couple hours.  I'm trying to compute the area of a polygon and use a loop to print a table of values.  I am using python

```
# This program computes 
# the area of polygons
import math

def main():
    side_length = get_side_length()
    report (side_length)

def report( side_length ):
    length = side_length(get_side_length)
    print('Side Length     Number of Sides     area')

def polygon_area( num_sides, side_length ):
    for num_sides in range(3, 10):
        area = (num_sides * side_length * side_length) \
        / (4 * math.tan(math.pi / num_sides)) 


def get_side_length():
    side_length = int(input( 'Input the length of a side '))
    return side_length


# start the program
main()
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What goes wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to great a loop saying if i have a length of 4 for the line what the area would be if the number of lines is 3 through 9.  What im having aproblem with is getting it to actually work

Comment: you need to input the number of sides, either as a fixed value or from the user

Comment: kponz i can't use the range function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things going on here, and although your question might be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, here's a way to accomplish it:

```
# This program computes 
# the area of polygons
import math

def main():
    side_length = get_side_length()
    for number_of_sides in range(3, 10):
        report (side_length, number_of_sides)

def report(side_length, number_of_sides):
    area = polygon_area(number_of_sides, side_length)
    print('Side Length: {0}    Number of Sides: {1} Area: {2}'.format(side_length, number_of_sides, area))

def polygon_area( num_sides, side_length ):
    area = (num_sides * side_length * side_length) / (4 * math.tan(math.pi / num_sides)) 

def get_side_length():
    return int(input( 'Input the length of a side '))

# start the program
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def report( side_length ):
    length = side_length(get_side_length)
    print('Side Length     Number of Sides     area')
```

The middle line of this block is strange. `side_length` is a number passed as a parameter, but then you seem to be trying to call it as a function. Just delete that line.

You never call `polygon_area` and you never make use of the value it calculates. I guess you want to move that code into `report` and make it print the result?